# hover::after and content doesn't work CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a code that in mobile view, the "li" flex-direction become column and also the on the right-hand side a white border appears on hover, but it doesn't work. can you point out which part I'm doing wrong? or which of the .hover ones I put in my code is correct? , I still can't understand the after: and before: yet.
thank you for your help.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) { 
  ul {
     width:100%;
    flex-direction: column;
      
  } 
  .hover{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .hover::after{
    content: "(border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;)";
  }
}
```

I also added the   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: This is clearly wrong `content: "(border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;`

Comment: thank you. how should I use content? should I leave it empty?

Answer (score 1):

1. On a mobile device, the hover does not work (unless you press) because there is no mouse. (Or you just resized the screen and still use the mouse).
2. According to what you wrote you have a class called hover.
   If you want to use hover try ":hover" instead of ".hover".

for example:

```css
li:hover::after{
    content: 'test';
}
```